# What units is the pool_recycle flag in? [SQLAlchemy]

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

When connecting to a engine in SQLAlchemy, you can set a pool_recycle flag to prevent MySQL disconnecting automatically after 8 hours. Does anyone know what this pool_recycle flag's unit? Is it minutes, hours, or seconds? I couldn't find it in the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#setting-pool-recycle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class sqlalchemy.pool.Pool(creator, recycle=-1, echo=None, use_threadlocal=False, logging_name=None, reset_on_return=True, listeners=None, events=None, _dispatch=None)
```

[snip]

recycle – If set to non -1, number of seconds between connection recycling, which means upon checkout, if this timeout is surpassed the connection will be closed and replaced with     a newly opened connection. Defaults to -1.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/pooling.html